# If a switch doesn't support multicast, are multicast packets simply flooded out all ports?

Tags: multicast

If a switch doesn't support multicast, are multicast packets simply flooded out all ports? This would allow multicast enabled hosts to at least still receive the multicast frames.

Follow up question. If a Router doesn't support Multicast, I presume multicast packets it receives are simply dropped?

Comment: All switches support multicast,, and multicast _frames_ (mot _packets_) are flooded out every other switch interface, unless the switch supports IGMP snooping, but link-local multicast frames are supposed to be flooded regardless of IGMP snooping. Multicast routing is very different than unicast routing, and it is designed to prevent multicast _packets_ from going where they are not wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multicast is a special case of broadcast. If a switch does not have any specific handling for multicast (eg. igmp snooping), multicast traffic is simply broadcast, and floods to all ports.